# javascript RegEx that alert user if the name is more than 10

Tags: javascript, html, regex

First of all I need a good and simple RegEx book that explain simply what I should do ...

and I need a javascript function that check onchange what the user entered in name textbox ... if the name >= 10 characters continue else it send him an error "The name you entered must be 10 characters or less"

Comment: Do you have any code with an attempt to solve this?

Comment: A regular expression seems like overkill for that

Comment: I agree that it's an overkill, though it was fun writing a pattern to match any string with at least 10 characters`..........`

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/ , is an amazing tool to learn and check your regularexpressions, but I agree with LUIS PEREIRA comment.. seems like you didn't even tried. I mean, there is no textarea element in HTML, input or textfield, to avoid downvotes research a litlle first.

Comment: in name I don't need special characters ... maxlength attribute is not enough ... sorry guys but I'm beginner and self learning ... I heard about RegEx yesterday only .. and I need to try them ... 
when I typed this : /^\w{0,10}  but no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jquery/javascript to verify the 10 logical characters in field(Trailing spaces could be excluded). using `maxlength` attribute of HTML will not exclude spaces.

```
function validateLength()
{
 var len=    $("#<Id of inputfield>").val().trim().length();
if(len<=10)
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Use this method on your submit/onclick button.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `maxlength` html attribute instead of regex:

```
<input maxlength="10" />
```